# why am I not able to add border width

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS. I am trying to create border around text but the border is not appearing. Also is there an editor online that tell me about mistakes in tags like even typos?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html>
 <head>
 <title> CSS Practice 
 </title>
 <style>
 p. one {border-width: 2px; border-style: solid;}
 </style>
 </head>

 <body>
 <p class="one"> My name is xyz </p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Any basic css tutorial would have provided you with an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the space in your selector:

```
p.one {border-width: 2px; border-style: solid;}
```

`p .one` selects an element with the class `one` that is a descendant of a paragraph tag, while `p.one` selects paragraphs that have the class `one`.

Comment: Interesting. Can you give me  few more examples or direct me to a link where I can learn more about this.

Comment: Sure thing. This is a great page to read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors

Answer (score 3):

Your selector should be `p.one`, not `p .not`.

`p .not` will look for `.not` inside `p`.

```css
p.one {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<p class="one">My name is xyz</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the given answers about the CSS problem. About your other question, some editors help you when it comes to mistakes in tags and typos. For instance, Sublime Text, Notepad++, Atom and others have good syntax highlighting and features to indent your code, close open tags and point out typos. HTML and CSS can be validated against the W3C standards via the W3C Validator. Some editors have features to validate your code but you can always use there online validation tools.

Hope this helps with your coding.

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly fine!
Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/zb31m0de/

You were having a space between **`.`** and **`one`**
Let me teach you one more thing:-). Make your box beautiful with a shadow and some padding.

```
box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px 3px #CCC;
padding:10px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
border : 2px solid black;
```

Increasing the 2px may increase your border width.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `p.one{...}` as increases the CSS specificity. It is useful when you strictly need to style targeted `p` element only.

In your example, you can just put one **semantic** classname and use required property and values. FYI, `p.classname` and `.classname` have different meaning and treats differently. eg. if you use `p.classname` the style will be applied only to a `p` element which have a class of `.classname` but if you define your selector as `.classname` then you can use it any element even if its not a `p` element.

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
p.one{border:2px solid #000}
```